# Invalidate selected perl cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, foreach, invalidation

I have the following perl script.
I need it to invalidate all cookies that are not in the `validCookies` hash. Note this is only the upper part of my code, the rest deals with printing all the cookies in the `@cookieArray()` and that works for me.
Since the right cookies are being set that I need to set manually later on in the code. ATM the code is not invalidating the cookies, anyone see why?

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Cookie;    


@cookieArray = ();

#hash of cookie names that should not be set to null
%validCookies = ( cName=> 0, cAddress => 0, cCity => 0, cProvince => 0, cPostalCode => 0, cMail => 0, cDate => 0);

%cook = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
foreach $name ($cook){
 if(exists ($validCookies{$name})){

 } else {
   $temp = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>$name, -value =>"");
   push(@cookieArray, $temp);
 }
}
```

Comment: Post code that at least has a hope of working. What is that foreach going to iterate over?

Comment: The array is looping over the %cook, which is an associative array with all the cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invalidate a cookie, you must expire it. The following code expires all except the protected cookie names.

It is not necessary to use the CGI::Cookie low-level interface. All the functionality is already exposed through the `cookie` method.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use CGI qw();
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my %protected_names = map { $_ => undef }
    qw(cName cAddress cCity cProvince cPostalCode cMail cDate);

my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header(
    -type => 'text/plain',
    -cookie => [
        map {
            $cgi->cookie(
                -name => $_,
                -value => (exists($protected_names{$_})
                    ? $cgi->cookie($_)
                    : q()
                ),
            )
        } $cgi->cookie
    ],
);
print Dumper [$cgi->cookie];
```

Comment: Hey daxim I'm sure your solution would work, but I still have to add more cookies after. To my knowledge I can only print out cookies once. That is why I was pushing all the cookies into an array.  My problem also wasn't to expire (the cookies only last for a session), what I needed to do is set the value in the cookies to null.

Comment: It **does** work, I actually ran and tested it. I have the feeling you did not. - I am also just sending cookies once, in the `header` method which builds and sends the HTTP header. I am also collecting them in a list before sending, that's what the `map` does; there is no need for a named array. - Edited the to answer to set the values to an empty string instead of expiring.

Comment: Works for me too. Cookies not in `%protected_names` are set to null.